# Feedburner doesn't push RSS updates to Facebook Page

Tags: facebook, rss, feedburner

I have publicized my Feedburner feed and added Twitter and Facebook accounts.

1 - I don't know how Google can verify Facebook page, and tried looking everywhere

2 - Yet, Feedburner successfully posts to Twitter

How to troubleshoot this? How to make Feedburner successfully post latest feed to Facebook page? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like [IFTTT](http://IFTTT.com) which provides recipes triggered when your feed updates.